# Creating a Record using PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, record, procedure

I have a pretty basic procedure that I am trying to create.  I just need to create a record for a single row from a table.  What am I missing?  The error code that I am receiving is "encountered the symbol declare when expecting...."

```
Create or Replace Procedure Luke as
Declare
Type type_basket is record(Term_code section.term_code%type, 
                           Subject_Code section.subject_code%type, 
                            Course_Number section.course_number%type, 
                              Section section.section%type);
Rec_Basket type_basket;

Begin
  Select term_code, subject_code, course_number, section into Rec_basket
    from Enrollment
      where term_code=201201 and course_number=105;

dbms.output_put.line(rec_basket.term_code);

end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DECLARE` is only needed for [anonymous blocks and subblocks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#LNPLS141), you [don't use it to declare stored procedure variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS653):

> **Note:**
>   The declarative part of a subprogram does not begin with the keyword DECLARE, as the declarative part of an anonymous block does.

So remove that line:

```
Create or Replace Procedure Luke as
  Type type_basket is ...
  Rec_Basket type_basket;
Begin
  Select ...
end;
/
```

You could use a `%rowtype` variable  instead of explicitly declaring a record type, and select the whole row into that, but I assume your assignment is specifically about records.